# need to construct 3 lists from 3 columns in a HIVE UDF

Tags: java, hadoop, hive

I am new to hive. I am facing troubles in writing HIVE UDF where in i am passing 3 arguments as 3 columns to UDF. I need to construct 3 lists of with the columns values. Based on which i will perform my logic on the 3 lists and return a string for each record.

My code has to looks like this.

```
  public String evaluate(int column1, int column2, String column3){

 ArryList column1List //column1List has to all column1 values
 ArryList column2List //column2List has to all column2 values
 ArryList column3List //column3List has to all column3 values


 }
```

Can some one please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm interpreting your intent correctly, you can do this with Hive's build-in function `collect_list`.  For example:

```
SELECT collect_list(field1) FROM my_table;
```

This will assemble a list of all values occurring in the `field1` column of `my_table`.

Depending on what you need to do with those lists, you may find that it's easier to simply pass in the result of `collect_list` to your UDF (since they will already be lists).

More documentation here:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF